# jQuery image swap on nav hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to do an image swap on the navigation when a user hovers over a menu item. It needs to load a different image depending on the height of the element.

So far I have this, which works to some extent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.mainlevel').hover(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > 15) {
            $('a.mainlevel').mouseenter(function() {
                $('a.mainlevel:hover').css('background-image','url(/images/menuHoverBig.gif)');
            });
            $('a.mainlevel').mouseleave(function() {
                $('a.mainlevel').css('background','#505051');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('a.mainlevel').mouseenter(function() {
                $('a.mainlevel:hover').css('background-image','url(/images/menuHover.gif)');
            });
            $('a.mainlevel').mouseleave(function() {
                $('a.mainlevel').css('background','#505051');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that if I hover over element of size X, it loads the correct image but then when I hover over element of size Y, it loads the image for X. If you then hover over Y again it works correctly. Going back to X, the Y image loads until a second hover.

I'm not really that up on jQuery so it's probably something obvious, but I can't work it out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you should change selector to $(this). And also you dont need `mouseenter` end `mouseleave` functions

```
$((function() {
                  $('a.mainlevel').hover(function()
                  {
                    var _image = "url(/images/menuHover.gif)";
                    if ($(this).height()> 15){
                        _image = "url(/images/menuHoverBig.gif)";
                     $(this).css("backround",_image);
                 },
                 function(){
                      $(this).css('background','#505051');

                 });


                });
```

Comment: Hi @Yorgo 
Thanks for replying.
Trying your solution "give missing ) after argument list"
I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: i fixed up, sory i forgot the ) character

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that you are assigning `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers within the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions of `hover()`, and you are also referencing all `.mainlevel` elements when setting the `css`, not just the current element. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.mainlevel').hover(
        function() {
            var $el = $(this);      
            var bgImage = 'url(/images/menuHover.gif)';
            if ($el.height() > 15)
                bgImage = 'url(/images/menuHoverBig.gif)');                 
            $el.css('background-image', bgImage);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background', '#505051');
        }
    )
});
```